# Cut off end of file without creating a new one

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have a program that spits out a very large text file that is 75% garbage at the end.  Id like to be able to just cut the end off the file with out looping through each line and printing to a new file. Is there anyway to do this in python?

its hard to provide an example because it would be a very large file. ill give it a try:

`good line
good line
bad line
bad line
bad line
bad line
bad line
EOF`

I would like to cut off all of the bad lines. Lets assume for the moment that I could `seek()` to the spot where I need to cut off the file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean without seeing the code you're talking about.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `truncate()` method of file objects, it truncates the file from current position (or to a specified size, but your request implies you're actually reading the file when the decision to delete it's tail is made).

You can check the method documentation here:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: why was this voted down?  It looks like this and seek might be what i am looking for.

Comment: Looks legit to me. Also you can redirect output of the verbose program to a unix command "head" or implement something similar on Windows.